# Value types in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

Value type is the one which does not have its own entity,and does not have its own lifecycle.
One more property of a value type says that it cannot have shared references. For example-
If there is a class User which has an instance variable address which points towards the object of Address class.Even If two users have the same address then also they cannot point towards the same object.

What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that if you had two users having the same instance of address, the following would modify the address of both users, which you obviously don't want:

```
user1.getAddress().setStreet("new street");
```

Both addresses, even if they contain the same values, represent the cells of two different rows in the database, so they should be different instances.